# How to add autotools nature/builder to CDT project? How to import/link autotools project?

Tags: eclipse, autotools, eclipse-cdt

I have "autotools" project folder, which contains (optional) `autogen.sh` script, necessary `configure` script and then uses makefile.

All this works fine from command line.

When importing in Eclipse, I see no option to import "autotools" project. If I import as makefile project, the resulting project does not contain GNU Autotools builder in builder list. And I see no way to add it.

Is it possible to add "autotools nature" to already created project? Or is it possible to add autotools builder to a project?

Or may be it is possible to import project as autotools one from the beginning?